# succesfully running gazebo but cannot run simulator_gazebo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hey guys take a look at the following code:

successful run:

```
root@ubuntu:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks# gazebo
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.6.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
```

gazebosim.org

```
Msg Waiting for master.Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.6.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
gazebosim.org

Warning [parser.cc:361] Converting a deprecated SDF source[/usr/share/gazebo-1.6/worlds/empty.world].
Warning [Converter.cc:61]   Version[1.3] to Version[1.4]
  Please use the gzsdf tool to update your SDF files.
    $ gzsdf convert [sdf_file]
Warning [parser.cc:361] Converting a deprecated SDF source[/home/konet/.gazebo/models/sun/model.sdf].
Set SDF value
Warning [Converter.cc:61]   Version[1.2] to Version[1.4]
  Please use the gzsdf tool to update your SDF files.
    $ gzsdf convert [sdf_file]
Warning [parser.cc:361] Converting a deprecated SDF source[/home/konet/.gazebo/models/ground_plane/model.sdf].
Set SDF value
Warning [Converter.cc:61]   Version[1.2] to Version[1.4]
  Please use the gzsdf tool to update your SDF files.
    $ gzsdf convert [sdf_file]
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ //127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 192.168.0.19

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ //127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 192.168.0.19
```

non-successful run:

```
root@ubuntu:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks# roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch
... logging to /home/konet/.ros/log/6fa89b8e-a327-11e2-909e-68a3c42c6822/roslaunch-ubuntu-3071.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server //ubuntu:41494/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /use_sim_time

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo/gazebo)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo/gui)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [3085]
ROS_MASTER_URI=//localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 6fa89b8e-a327-11e2-909e-68a3c42c6822
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [3098]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [3112]
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [3121]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.3.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
//gazebosim.org

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.3.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
//gazebosim.org

Warning [parser.cc:361] Converting a deprecated SDF source[/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world].
Set SDF value
  Version[1.2] to Version[1.3]
  Please use the gzsdf tool to update your SDF files.
    $ gzsdf convert [sdf_file]
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ //127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 192.168.0.19
[ INFO] [1365740057.248876597]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
Error [Rendering.cc:37] Failed to load the Rendering engine subsystem
unable to find OpenGL rendering system. OGRE is probably installed incorrectly. Double check the OGRE cmake output, and make sure OpenGL is enabled.
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ //127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 192.168.0.19
[ INFO] [1365740057.861764237]: joint trajectory plugin missing <updateRate>, defaults to 0.0 (as fast as possible)
Error [Rendering.cc:37] Failed to load the Rendering engine subsystem
unable to find OpenGL rendering system. OGRE is probably installed incorrectly. Double check the OGRE cmake output, and make sure OpenGL is enabled.
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing
exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must
reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'gazebo::common::Exception'
Aborted (core dumped)
[gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid 3121, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/konet/.ros/log/6fa89b8e-a327-11e2-909e-68a3c42c6822/gazebo_gui-3.log].
log file: /home/konet/.ros/log/6fa89b8e-a327-11e2-909e-68a3c42c6822/gazebo_gui-3*.log
^C[gazebo-2] killing on exit
[gazebo-2] escalating to SIGTERM
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

any suggestions in the code?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60521/succesfully-running-gazebo-but-cannot-run-simulator_gazebo/) by [konet](https://answers.ros.org/users/4438/konet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your are using a too new version of gazebo with ROS...
What can help:

```
/<path>/gazebo$ source setup.bash
```

then run in a terminal:

```
$ rosrun gazebo gzsdf convert /<path>/your.sdf
```

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1